# Simple SQL help to update table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
select orders.ID, books.Quantity from orders, Books
where customerid = '52467'
and Status = 'ready'
and orders.ID = books.OrderID
```

I want to update books.quantity = '1'

```
Update Books
SET books.Quantity = '1'
```

Just not sure how to write the query.

Comment: What flavour of sql are you using? mysql? sql-server?

Comment: MS SQL is what I am using

Comment: You should always add the specific dbms to your question's tags

Comment: You shouldn't be using string literals for numbers. `'1'` is a character value, `1` is a number.

Comment: Seems like your DB schema is very weird... how come the Books table has an OrderID reference? Can books only be ordered once?

Answer (score 2):

IN SQL-SERVER you can do:

```
update books
set books.Quantity = '1'
from books b
inner join orders o on o.ID = b.OrderID    
where o.customerid = '52467'
  and o.status = 'ready'
```

Comment: Very minor quibble, I'd change the first line to `update Books`. I hate having to search through the full query (which sometimes gets very long) to find what table is actually being updated.

Comment: @PhilipKelley. That's a fair argument for an edit i can make :)

Comment: Here is what SQL is reporting back when I run that query:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.Quantity" could not be bound.

Comment: Sorry. change it to books.quantity. In response to the first comment from Philip i changed b to books and forgot to change in set

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    Books
SET
    Books.Quantity = '1'
FROM
    Books
INNER JOIN
    Orders
ON
    Books.orderID = Orders.ID
WHERE Orders.customerid = '52467'
  and Orders.status = 'ready'
```

is this what you need? If your using this in code such as C# then turn it into a stored procedure if you wish and then customerID and Status becomes Dynamic as you will use paramters.

```
USE [Your Database Name]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateBookQuantity]
@CustomerID varchar(50),
@Status varchar(50)
AS
UPDATE
    Books
SET
    Books.Quantity = '1'
FROM
    Books
INNER JOIN
    Orders
ON
    Books.orderID = Orders.ID
WHERE Orders.customerid = @customerID
  and Orders.status = @Status
```

just popped it in there if its going to be a frequent thing you need to do.